# Equivalent of Java's "ByteBuffer.putType()" in C#

Tags: c#, java, memorystream, bytebuffer

I am trying to format a byte array in C#, by porting a code from Java. In Java, the methods "buf.putInt(value);", buf.putShort, buf.putDouble, (and so forth) are used. However I don't know how to port this to C#. I have tried the MemoryStream class, but there is no method to put a specific type at the end of the byte array.

Question: What is the equivalent of Java's "ByteBuffer.putType(value)" in C#?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write.aspx) and your MemoryStream:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(myByte);
    writer.Write(myInt32);
    writer.Write("Hello");
}

byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use this solution in the end :)

Comment: Most of your variable names have 6 letters in them but a few don't. My OCD is kicking in and I almost want to fix them...

Answer (score 5):

Try the [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) class:

```
using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(...))
{
    binaryWriter.Write(323);
    binaryWriter.Write(3487d);
    binaryWriter.Write("Hello");
}
```

Comment: We both enjoy writing 3 things, including Hello.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's exactly what I was looking for :). However, how can I get back to a byte array after using the binary writer?

Comment: If the binary writer is wrapped around a `MemoryStream`, you can call `ToArray` on it and get a byte array.

Comment: I feel completely stupid asking another question, but, how do I wrap it around a MemoryStream?

Comment: Lazlo, you can see my answer for how you "wrap it around a memory stream" (I don't feel its my place to edit Kent's).

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting to use the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class. The main difference is that these methods return an array of bytes instead of altering an existing array.

(This is a replacement for the specific methods mentioned; for a replacement of the entire ByteBuffer class, see the other replies.)