# What is the equivalent of Java's ByteBuffer.wrap in C#?

Tags: c#, java, memorystream, bytebuffer

```
byte[] input = new byte[] {2, 4, 5, 2, 1};
ByteBuffer bytebuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(input);
```

`ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[] array)` method makes buffer and array are inter-connected, modifications to the buffer will cause the array to be modified and vice versa.

The equivalent of `ByteBuffer` in C# is memorystream. But I don't know how to connect memorystream with array likes `ByteBuffer.wrap()` method did.

Can someone tell what is the equivalent of `ByteBuffer.wrap()` in C#?
I have searched everywhere but could not find the answer at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078348/byte-collection-based-similar-with-bytebuffer-from-java

Comment: hi @Krishna, I've read that post, but it still did not help.

Comment: I don't know what exact behavior you are missing from linked question, but check `MemoryStream` constructors - there is one to use given array as buffer...

Comment: Why do you need the array and the byte operations linked in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use a binary writer and a memory stream.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261543/equivalent-of-javas-bytebuffer-puttype-in-c-sharp)

I have not flagged this question as a duplicate only because you didn't ask precisely what that other poster did. I am not sure what to do in that case, but still wish to help you.  Good luck!

Here's the code from that link for posterity's sake:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(myByte);
    writer.Write(myInt32);
    writer.Write("Hello");
}
byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: hi @Morisson, the link you provided is linking back to this question. Could you fix it please?

Comment: I don't think this is a right solution. The code you gave is just for inputting array to memorystream using BinaryWriter, it is not a method to connect stream with array. Even the last code byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray(); will result an error because the stream  cannot be accessed because the stream has been closed by the BinaryWriter.

Comment: @NoeL - care to give link (MSDN?) to prove your last statement about `ToArray` failing on closed/disposed `MemeoryStream`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, ToArray() doesn't close the stream, BinaryWriter did. I don't find any MSDN link, but there is a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084813/why-a-binarywriter-closes-the-outer-stream-on-disposal-and-how-to-prevent-that I have tested it and BinaryWriter always close the stream

Comment: @NoeL I'm not sure why you dislike MSDN, but this may be useful link [MemoryStream.ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) - "Note:This method works when the MemoryStream is closed."

Comment: Don't know how I messed that up, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `wrap` would be to use the constructor of `MemoryStream` that takes a `byte[]`: [`MemoryStream(byte[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-io-memorystream-ctor(system-byte())). This 'wraps' the original array, and as such is a fixed-size buffer.

```
byte[] input = new byte[] {2, 4, 5, 2, 1};
using var ms = new MemoryStream(input);
```

The contrast with the other answer being that this preserves the contents of the array (important if you want to read from it) and doesn't create any copies, which I understand was the point of your question.

Otherwise, to read/write logical values to the buffer/stream, the answer is much the same as the existing answer: use a `StreamWriter` and/or `StreamReader`.

```
using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8, leaveOpen: true))
{
    bw.Write(12356789);
    
    try
    {
        bw.Write(12356789); // additional write will throw due to lack of space
    }
    catch {}
}

using (var br = new BinaryReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8, leaveOpen: true))
{
    // reset position before reading
    ms.Position = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(br.ReadInt32());
}

// check we modified the original buffer (ToArray would return a copy)
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", input));
```